# Login failed for user 'sa' and Pipes Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis

I'm getting the following error when trying to log into my system in asp.net  (locally and IIS)

> Login failed for user 'sa'.

The problem is that in no connection string we are using the SA login to connect to the database (SQL SERVER 2008).
Using the same connection string user and password, I can seamlessly connect to Management Studio ..

```
<add name="AppConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=**IPADRESS**;Initial Catalog=**DATABASE**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**USER**;Password=**PSW**" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

An error also appears from time to time, altering with that of SA

> No process is on the other end of the pipe

The site was in production for over 3 weeks and we had no problem so far ..
Can it be some IIS configuration, or will it be SQL?